# How to hook a function for a particular shared ELF library?

Tags: linux, redirect, shared-libraries, hook, elf

LD_PRELOAD hooks some functions for the entire process, but I need to hook a particular function for only one dynamically linked library by its name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the article [Redirecting functions in shared ELF libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/elf-redirect.aspx). There's code of ELF hooking attached.